# Implicit expression for property

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I know I can write the following to generate lambda expression:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> lambda = s => s.Length == 5;
```

But is there any way to automatically generate expression for property? In other words is there strongly-typed analogue of this:

```
var property = Expression.Property("Name")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a lambda which returns the `Length` property:

```
Expression<Func<string, int>> lambda = s => s.Length;
```

If you don't want the full lambda, but only the `MemberExpression` which accesses the property, you can do that:

```
var propertyExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Expressions<Func<ClassWithProperty, PropertyReturnType>> lambda = C => C.Name;
```